# Inverse kinematics in KDL without rotation

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to use KDL to do inverse kinematics. However I am not interested in the orientation of the end effector, but only in the location. Is there a way to specify this in KDL? The function `CartToJnt` only seems to accept a Frame with a rotation matrix. Is there maybe a different way to do this in KDL?

Comment: I am not a KDL user so take this as just a suggestion.  Have you tried putting a 3x3 identity matrix in for the rotation submatrix?

Comment: I have considered it, but the identity rotation is also specifies a orientation. Therefor the algorithm tries to optimize using that orientation. And if that orientation cannot be reached the displacement is also less accurate. I want the algorithm to totally ignore the rotation.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2):

The KDL Ik solver **KDL::ChainIkSolverPos_LMA** can be construct with a [weight matrix](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/orocos_kdl/html/classKDL_1_1ChainIkSolverPos__LMA.html#a5322326848d618e0ec2af8683344274e). You should be able to solve using only the end effector's target position by setting rotation components weights to 0.